# slice a list up to a given element

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

If you have a list `my_list = ['a', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'b', 'f']` and you want to construct a sublist, containing all elements up to a given one, for example `my_list_up_to_c = ['a', 'd', 'e']`, how can this be done in a way that scales easily? Also can this be made faster by using numpy arrays?

Comment: `my_list[:my_list.index(2)]` I think. It should be similar to looping the list once, returning at the first instance of the lookup value. Should be O(n) in the worst case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The least amount of code would probably be using [`.index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) (note that this searches till the first occurence of the element in said list):

```
>>> my_list = ['a', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'b', 'f']
>>> my_list
['a', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'b', 'f']
>>> my_list[:my_list.index('c')]          # excluding the specified element
['a', 'd', 'e']
>>> my_list[:my_list.index('c')+1]        # including the specified element
['a', 'd', 'e', 'c']
```

The time complexity of the call to `.index()` is `O(n)`, meaning it will at most iterate once over the list. The list slicing has complexity `O(k)` (according to [this source](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#list)), meaning it depends on the size of the slice.

So in the worst case the element you look for is at the end of the list, so your search will run till the end of the list (`O(n)`) and the slice will copy the whole list as well (also `O(n)`), resulting in a worst case of `O(2n)` which is still linear complexity.

Answer (score 2):

Use index() to get the first occurrence of a list item. Then use the slice notation to get the desired part of the list.

```
>>> my_list = ['a', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'b', 'f']
>>> my_list[:my_list.index('c')]
['a', 'd', 'e']
```

Answer (score 1):

The itertools solution

```
In[9]: from itertools import takewhile
In[10]: my_list = ['a', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'b', 'f'] 
In[11]: list(takewhile(lambda x: x != 'c', my_list))
Out[11]: ['a', 'd', 'e']
```

In Haskell it would be

```
takeWhile ((/=) 'c') "adecbf"
```

Comment: Note that this does not allow to include the specified element in the resulting list. Maybe that is what OP wanted, but it is worth to point that limitation out.